# Fail to run a bash command on python with subprocess and sed

Tags: python, bash

My goal is to execute the following bash command in Python and store its output:

```sh
echo 'sudo ./run_script.sh -dates  \\{\\'2017-11-16\\',\\'2017-11-29\\'\\}'|sed 's;\\\\;\\;'
```

When I run this command in bash, the output is: `sudo ./run_script.sh -dates  \{\'2019-10-05\',\'2019-10-04\'\}`

My initial idea was to replace the double backslash by a single backslash in Python. As ridiculous as it seems, I couldn't do it in Python (only when using `print()` the output is as I would like but I can't store the output of `print()` and str() doesn't convert \ to . So I decided to do it in bash.

```py
import subprocess

t= 'some \\ here'

cmd = "echo \'"+ t+"\'|sed 's;\\\\;\\;'"
ps = subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

ps.stdout
Out[6]: b"sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command\n"
```

Running Python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18

Comment: Using `sed` to replace backslashes is rather pointless, though. Python can do this intuitively and much more efficiently. `print(r'sudo ./run_script.sh -dates  \\{\\'2017-11-16\\',\\'2017-11-29\\'\\}'.replace('\\\\', '\\'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using subprocess.check_output instead. You're also forgetting an extra backslash for every backslash in your command.

```
import subprocess

command = "echo 'some \\\\here'|sed 's;\\\\\\\\;\\\\;'"
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode()
print(output) # prints your expect result "some \here"
```

Comment: thanks, your code runs but doesn't do what I want. As I said, the output I want is 'some \here' without using the print function. The whole purpose of doing all this is that I can't obtain a single backslash without using the print function. And I need it to call another script.

Comment: @paul95121 The print function is just to show that it works. If you do anything with output you will see that it contains 'some \here' as you described.

Comment: actually I use this to call a bash script which launches a Matlab command. And I do this using os.system(output) where output refers to the result of subprocess command. And unfortunately the double back slashes remain there and the script fails. I will edit my post to make it  more clear.

Comment: Without information about the *actual* command you need help with I don't think you will receive any better answers. It is extremely unclear what you need; the requirement to pass the output from one shell to another certainly seems misdirected, if not outright erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your question I kinda understood what you wanted.

```py
a = r'some \here'
print(a) #some \here
```

Again, raw string literals...

Comment: thanks! this also doesn't output what I want. It outputs: b'some \\here\n' where as I want the following output 'some \here'

Comment: I just reread your question. Try this then: a = r'some \here'